# Bind a ControlTemplate value to a styles property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, styles

I have a `ControlTemplate` for my custom button.

Im trying to bind the `<Border.Background>` in the ControlTemplate to the Styles `Background` property.

**XAML**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NumberButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="Button" >
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>



<Style x:Key="NumberButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NumberButtonControlTemplate}" />        
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumSpringGreen" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
</Style>
```

How do I make the `ControlTemplate` `BorderBackground` Property get the value of the Style Background ?

What I have done above is right, is there something Im missing ?

Answer (score -1):

The `Background` property on `Button` (and on `Border`) is of type `Brush` but you're attempting to use it as a `Color`. Use this instead:

```
<Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
```

Comment: I think I accidently down voted this on my laptop. SO states that if you edit your anser I can change my vote (sorry I didnt know I voted it down)